# App is slower after renaming package

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Yesterday I renamed my project package from com.example.myname.myapp to com.mycompany.myapp
today I have noticed that my app is way slower than it was.. (at least +1 second to load an intent)
and I wonder ,could it be because of that renaming? or maybe it is something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a different name for the package. I don't think it should be ANY slower due to a certain name.

You can try completely removing the app from your test device (through the settings) which will wipe all traces of it, and then installing it again. A simple package name change shouldn't have an impact like that.

You can check this out for a cool talk on how to write quick android apps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4znvD-7VDA

Comment: Thanks for your reply , and what about app permissions? I added permission for Internet in order to add ads

Comment: @james Not sure. I don't think that simply ADDING the permission will slow down your app. That may be worth asking as a new question.